# Filter numbers in array depending on if they are even or not

Tags: arrays, ruby, database, filter, logstash

I am trying to get a range of numbers but only have the result be the same even/odd as the `@low` number `event` is a logstash variable, it works, @low and @high are ints.

```rb
def filter(event)
    @low = event.get('lowhousenumber').to_i
    @high = event.get('highhousenumber').to_i
    @arr = (@low..@high).to_a.partition { |v| v.even? }

        if @low%1==0
                return event.set('addressrange', @arr[0]) // needs to set even results
        else
                return event.set('addressrange', @arr[1]) // needs to set odd results
        end
end
```

the output for when `@low` is `500` and @high is `506` the output should be `500, 502, 504, 506` if `@low` is 501 and `@high` is `507` the output should be `501,503,505,507`

Comment: How about `n = @high-@low+1; (0..n).step(2).map { |i| @low + i }`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland `@low.step(@high, 2).to_a` ?

Comment: @steenslag, thanks, I learned something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logstash needs to return an array of events so this should do the trick

```
def filter(event)
    @low = event.get('lowhousenumber').to_i
    @high = event.get('highhousenumber').to_i

    filter = @low.even? ? 'even?' : 'odd?'

    @arr = (@low..@high).to_a.select{|i| i.send(filter) }

    event.set('addressrange', @arr)

    return [event]
end
```